# How to check if parentheses are balanced?

Tags: php, parentheses, braces

Write a function called `validBraces` that takes a string of braces, and determines if the order of the braces is valid. validBraces should return true if the string is valid, and false if it's invalid.

All input strings will be nonempty, and will only consist of open parentheses `(`, closed parentheses `)`, open brackets `[`, closed brackets `]`, open curly braces `{` and closed curly braces `}`.

What is considered Valid?

A string of braces is considered valid if all braces are matched with the correct brace. For example:

`(){}[]` and `([{}])` would be considered valid, while `(}`, `[(])`, and `[({})](]` would be considered invalid.

```
Specification
validBraces(braces)
```

Checks if the brace order is valid

Parameters
braces: String - A string representation of an order of braces

Return Value
Boolean - Returns true if order of braces are valid

Examples:

```
    Input   Output
validBraces( "(){}[]" )     true
validBraces( "(}" )         false
validBraces( "[(])" )       false
validBraces( "([{}])" )     true
```

Comment: Please read  the [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) and  [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822).

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty trivial assignment and you can use stack (i.e. array/list). You then iterate over input string char by char and once you detect opening bracket (`(`, `<`, `{` etc) you push that bracket on your stack (or append to the array, does not matter). And when you encounter closing bracket (`)`, `>`, `}` etc) then you pop **last element** from your stack. You then check if bracket type matches so when you have `>` then you should have popped `<` from your stack otherwise you stop the process complaining about mismatched brackets (or whatever). Once you done iterating without any errors your stack should be empty.

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

function validateBrackets(string $str): string {
    $map = [
        '(' => ')',
        '<' => '>',
        '{' => '}',
        '[' => ']',
    ];

    $stack = new \SplStack();
    for($i = 0; $i < \strlen($str); $i++) {
        if(\array_key_exists($str[$i], $map)) {
            // Push both the bracket and its index into the stack
            $stack->push([$str[$i], $i]);
        } elseif(\in_array($str[$i], $map)) {
            if($stack->isEmpty() || $map[$stack->top()[0]] != $str[$i]) {
                $expected = !$stack->isEmpty() ? $map[$stack->top()[0]] : '';
                return $expected !== ''
                    ? "Expecting '{$expected}' at pos. {$i}, found '{$str[$i]}'"
                    : "Unpaired bracket '{$str[$i]}' at pos. {$i}";
            }
            $stack->pop();
        }
    }

    // If the stack is not empty at the end, return the
    // first unpaired opening bracket and its position
    if (!$stack->isEmpty()) {
        $unpaired = $stack->top();
        return "Unpaired bracket '{$unpaired[0]}' at pos. {$unpaired[1]}";
    }

    return "OK";
}
```

and the test case:

```php
$tests = [
    "",
    "(<>)",
    "(<)",
    "<<",
    "<>{}()",
    "<>()}",
];
foreach($tests as $testStr) {
    printf("%-10s: %s" . \PHP_EOL, $testStr, validateBrackets($testStr));
}
```

would output

```
          : OK
(<>)      : OK
(<)       : Expecting '>' at pos. 2, found ')'
<<        : Unpaired bracket '<' at pos. 1
<>{}()    : OK
<>()}     : Unpaired bracket '}' at 4
```

Comment: More difficult with `[(])` as this would pass your logic.

Comment: Nope. It would work as expected - on `]` what you pop is `(` which is not a matching type for `]` so you can happily report invalid input string and not process further.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski would be kind enough to write out the solution code?

Comment: Here you go... :)

Answer (score -2):

Make one variable that counts in increment the number of '(' and then decrease from that -= for each ')' in the end, if that variable is = 0 then yes the parenthesis are balanced. Repeat the same for a different type of bracket.

Comment: This is a bit too simplistic. `[(])` is invalid, yet your algorithm would result in *valid*.