# How to check the expression is correct or not in javascript in sample of test cases?

Tags: javascript

I have below test cases in which i need to classify the correct expression in javascript.

```
(a) correct

((a)) correct

(a(b)) correct

(b) correct

(b  incorrect
```

You can see the last one is incorrect expression. How can we achieve this through javascript ?

Comment: You mean, check balance of the parentheses? That's a well-known interview question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56656660/how-to-check-if-parentheses-are-balanced

Comment: depending upon what `a` and `b` refers to your third expression can be incorrect.

Comment: Yeah it's interview question and i was stunned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle other types of brackets - {}, [] and the ():

```js
function matchBrackets(s) {
  let x = "";
  let c = [];
  let ok = true;
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    x = s.substr(i, 1);
    switch (x) {
      case "{":
        c.unshift("}");
        break;
      case "[":
        c.unshift("]");
        break;
      case "(":
        c.unshift(")");
        break;
      case "}":
        if (c[0] == "}") {
          c.shift();
        } else {
          ok = false;
        }
        break;
      case "]":
        if (c[0] == "]") {
          c.shift();
        } else {
          ok = false;
        }
        break;
      case ")":
        if (c[0] == ")") {
          c.shift();
        } else {
          ok = false;
        }
        break;
    }
    if (!ok) {
      break;
    }
  }
  if (c.length > 0) {
    ok = false;
  }
  return ok;
} 

let tocheck = [];
tocheck.push("a(b][}c");
tocheck.push("a(bc");
tocheck.push("a)(bc");
tocheck.push("a(b)[c]{(d)}");
tocheck.push("(a)");
tocheck.push("((a))");
tocheck.push("(a(b))");
tocheck.push("(b)");
tocheck.push("(b");
tocheck.push("))a((");

for (let i = 0; i < tocheck.length; i++) {
  console.log(tocheck[i] + ": " + matchBrackets(tocheck[i]));
}
```

This works in a similar way to the others but ensures that a closing bracket of any type must match with the last opening bracket of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly edited answer from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52969755/how-to-check-the-sequence-of-opening-and-closing-brackets-in-string)

```
function check(expr){
    const holder = []
    const openBrackets = ['(']
    const closedBrackets = [')']
    for (let letter of expr) { // loop trought all letters of expr
        if(openBrackets.includes(letter)){ // if its oppening bracket
            holder.push(letter)
        }else if(closedBrackets.includes(letter)){ // if its closing
            const openPair = openBrackets[closedBrackets.indexOf(letter)] // find his pair
            if(holder[holder.length - 1] === openPair){ // check if that pair is last element in array
                holder.splice(-1,1) //if so, remove it
            }else{ // if its not
                holder.push(letter)
                break // exit loop
            }
        }
    }
    if(holder.length === 0)
    {
      console.log("correct");
    }
    else{
      console.log("incorrect");
    }
}
check('(a)') /// give the string you want to check here
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a simple `stack` to store the opening parenthesis. Here is a brief explanation:

1. Convert the string into an array of characters
2. Create an empty stack
3. Iterate over each character:

   - if the character is not a parenthesis, continue to the next iteration
   - if it's an opening parenthesis, store it in the stack
   - if it's a closing parenthesis, then there are two possibilities:

     - if there are no corresponding opening parenthesis for it in the stack, then the string is not valid
     - if there is, then, pop the corresponding opposite parenthesis and continue normally

```js
let t1 = '(a)', t2 = '((b))', t3 = '(a(b))', t4 = '(b';
const isValid = (str) => {
     let characters = str.split('');
     let stack = [];
     for(let i = 0; i < characters.length; i++){
          let c = characters[i];
          if(c !== '(' && c !== ')') 
               continue;
          else if(c === '(')
               stack.push(c);
          else if(c === ')'){
               if(stack.length==0)
                    return false;
               else
                    stack.pop();
          }
     }
     return stack.length==0;
}

console.log(isValid(t1));
console.log(isValid(t2));
console.log(isValid(t3));
console.log(isValid(t4));
```

Answer (score 0):

If they want to check strings, then I would just loop over the string. I would have a variable (`characterCount`) that adds one for every '(' character and subtract one for every ')'. If the end result is 0, then it's correct formatting.

EDIT: I also need to check if `characterCount` is ever negative, which means that there is an incorrect formatting.

---

If it's an interview, ask them to clarify. Programmers that ask are more valuable than programmers that assume (and spend hours of valuable time coding wrong functionality).

```js
function checkFormatting(str) {
  const END_CHARACTER_BEFORE_START_CHARACTER = CORRECT_FORMATTING = 0;
  let characterCount = CORRECT_FORMATTING;
  let startCharacter = '(';
  let endCharacter = ')';
  
  for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    characterCount += Number(str[i] == startCharacter); // +1 if true
    characterCount -= Number(str[i] == endCharacter);   // -1 if false

    if (characterCount < END_CHARACTER_BEFORE_START_CHARACTER) { // EDIT
      console.log(str, false);
      return false;
    }
  }

  console.log(str, characterCount == CORRECT_FORMATTING);

  return characterCount == CORRECT_FORMATTING;
}

checkFormatting('(a)');    // true
checkFormatting('((a))');  // true
checkFormatting('(a(b))'); // true
checkFormatting('(b)');    // true
checkFormatting('(b');     // false
checkFormatting('))a((');  // false
```

Comment: How would that handle `))a((` ?